# How to transform pandas.core.series.Series to list?

Tags: python, pandas

I tried

```
print(type(numbers[2]))
numbers[2].tolist()
print(type(numbers[2]))
```

that doesn't work. I got

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Numbers is a matrix.

Comment: What do you mean by "Numbers is a matrix"?
If `numbers` is a pandas DataFrame with a column named `2` than `numbers[2].tolist()` should work.

Comment: You should include why it doesn't work, such as the error you are receiving. I just generated a `numpy.matrix` and ran `x[2].tolist()` and it was fine.

Comment: I editted the question

Comment: You can't modify an object's type in-place, `.tolist` returns a *new object* which you would have to assign to a variable or another reference. In this case, you probably want `numbers[2] = numbers[2].tolist()`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `.tolist()` call will not update your structure in-place. Instead the method will return a new list, without modifying the original `pd.Series` object.

That means we must assign the result to the original variable to update it. However, if the original variable is a slice of a `pd.DataFrame()` we cannot do this, since the `DataFrame` will automatically convert a `list` to a `pd.Series` when assigning.

That means, doing `numbers[2] = numbers[2].tolist()` will still have `numbers[2]` being a `pd.Series`. To actually get a list, we need to assign the output to another (perhaps new) variable, that is not part of a `DataFrame`.

Thus, doing

```
numbers_list = numbers[2].tolist()
print(type(numbers_list))
```

will output `<class 'list'>` as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't change anything in place since you are not assigning it:

```
print(type(numbers[2]))
numbers[2].tolist()
print(type(numbers[2]))
```

should be changed to:

```
print(type(numbers[2]))
numbers2list = numbers[2].tolist()
print(type(numbers2list))
```

returns:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'list'>
```